# How to rearrange elements using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to rearrange elements using jQuery ?

Orginal Code :

```
<p id="paragraph1">1</p>
<p id="paragraph2">2</p>
<p id="paragraph3">3</p>
<p id="paragraph4">4</p>
<p id="paragraph5">5</p>
```

After Rearrange (put p3 in p2's place)

```
<p id="paragraph1">1</p>
<p id="paragraph3">3</p>
<p id="paragraph2">2</p>
<p id="paragraph4">4</p>
<p id="paragraph5">5</p>
```

Comment: how are you wanting to rearrange them?  when someone clicks a button?  when someone drags the element around the screen?  more details please.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use [`.insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/):

```
$("#paragraph3").insertBefore("#paragraph2");
```

Slightly more elaborate example (clicking on a paragraph moves it up):

```
$("p").click(function() {
   $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev()); 
});
```

[**You can test both examples here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/Tt6uN/)