# Rearrange table row in basis of class using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example, 
I have this code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td class="last"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="last"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="another"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="another"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want this to be set like this using javascript:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td class="another"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="another"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="last"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="last"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Just what is needed is,
javascript should detect td with class "last" and take whole table row to bottom of the table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rearrange elements using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909907/how-to-rearrange-elements-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var last = $( '.last' );
last.parent().parent().append( last.parent() );
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/Jwg6M/).

`last.parent().parent()` is the `table` element, and `last.parent()` is the `tr` element.

`append` *moves* the DOM elements, so they're not "copied", they're moved to the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin:
http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo

Something more advanced:
http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$("table tr td.last").each(function () {
    $(this).parent().insertAfter($("table tr:last"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('td').each(function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass('another')) {
     $(this).insertBefore($('td:first'))
  }
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DbHVd/1/)