# is it possible to set the order of icon / button on jwplayer controlbar?

Tags: javascript, css, jwplayer

I want to make `JWplayer` skin like this

[image: skin design]

and this is my current progress

[image: my current jwplayer skin]

I have been looking for references to switch the order of `icon / button` on `controlbar`, according to the `jwplayer` documentation, the buttons on controlbar divided into 3 groups middle left and right . I want to move some of the button on the left group to the right group.

```
jwplayer("player").setup({
 skin: {
   url:"jwplayer/skins/player.css",
   name: "player"
},
width: "100%",
height: 100,
playlist: [{
  "file": "katachi.mp3",
  "title": "Shugo Tokumaru",
  "description": "Katachi"
},
{
  "file": "vektor.mp3",
  "title": "Shugo Tokumaru",
  "description": "Vektor feat"
},
{
  "file": "decorate.mp3",
  "title": "Shugo Tokumaru",
  "description": "Decorate"
}]
});
```

So, is there a way to set the order of the buttons in the `JWPlayer` controlbar?

Comment: may b you can but can you provide demo for the control bar so that we can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your player is HTML-based and not FLASH-based, than you have full access to HTML layout of player.

All you have to do is reorder elements:

1. Inspect elements to see some specific classes/ID's or just simply element indexes
2. Use some jQuery/js to reorder elements ([question about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909907/how-to-rearrange-elements-using-jquery))

Comment: hi @Justinas, ty for the answer. Its simple yet effective.
but first we need to call JWPlayer API to implement the DOM changes.
example:

`jwplayer().on('ready', function() {
    $(".class.PrevButton").insertBefore(".class.PlayButton");   
});`

i hope JWPlayer has configuration option for this buttons reordering later.

Comment: @fuadmakarim well, it's obvious that you first must have loaded player elements to make any changes with them...

Answer (score 0):

A way how to add elements to HTML5 based player, you can take a look at [following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36430044/1386969).